# JavaScript Hamburger Menu not opening

Tags: javascript

Here is the link to what I have copied into a website that I am creating. It works on the website but not when I have copied the code into a coded website I am working on.

It says the $ is not defined, but work on the site as intended

[image: 1]

Comment: sounds like jQuery isn't loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if you imported the Jquery library or not
see this link
[JQuery - $ is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined)